# Where to find MSSQL ODBC driver .so file?

Tags: 14.04, database, sql

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

From my Ubuntu machine I want to access an MS SQL 2005 server via ODBC. This MSSQL server is on our internal network. I've installed these packages: unixodbc, unixodbc-dev, unixodbc-bin, libodbc1, libtool, autotools-dev and several other dependencies. Also tdsodbc, freetds-bin, freetds-common, freetds-dev, libct4.

But I can't seem to find where the .so file is to use it in my DSN in /etc/odbc.ini. Which file do I use? Doing this: `echo "select 1"|isql -v mydsn` gives me this error:

```
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

The 'mydsn' is trying to point to /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so but it's not there. Which .so file do I set up in the /etc/odbc.ini file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

According to this link: http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html, it might be:

> /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so

Another possibility is:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so

This is for 64-bits architecture.

Once you found the right place, update the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` to reflect the changes.

Comment: It could also be in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu folder

Answer (score 0):

Below link might help if this case is still observed.
[TDSODBC](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libtdsodbc.so&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any)

Sharing here because I faced this too, recently.